# service configuration using springboot native.search-locations: file:/// yaml

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml

So first of all I have project that uses services , and config service to provide configuration to other services. If I provide  by VM argument:

```
-Dspring.cloud.config.server.native.search-locations=file:///"D:\work projects\...\src\config\config-repo\local"
```

then services can access config.
My problem is that I wanted to provide config by using profile springboot configuration  inside file applciation-local.yml (profile is activated):

```
spring.cloud.config.server.native.search-locations: file:///config/config-repo/local
```

the service config returns empty config like
"{}"

Is there problem with file:/// path?

[module-project tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dveMg.png)

Comment: Have you tried with `classpath:` instead of `file:///`?

Answer (score 0):

As  @alfcope commented, by using:

```
classpath:/config-repo/local
```

worked. Of course the config folder must be marked as resource folder.